# glViewport offset and ortho projection

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport, orthographic

In all tutorials I found about creating projection matrix based on viewport size all of them assumed that left bottom coordinates of viewport will be (0,0).

Now I want to draw to the different parts of the screen and for that purpose I want to switch viewports accordingly:

```
glViewport(0,0,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2); //left bottom
glViewport(0,windowHeight/2,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//left top
glViewport(windowWidth/2,0,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//right bottom
glViewport(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2,windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);//right top
```

Now I have a problem with defining my projection matrix. Without having any (x,y) offest I was using this code for calculating my ortho projection matrix:

```
if (m_WindowWidth > m_WindowHeight)
{
    auto viewportAspectRatio = (float)m_WindowWidth / (float)m_WindowHeight;

    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fLeft = (-1.0f) * m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fRight = m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fBottom = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fTop = m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fNear = -(10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fFar = (10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;

    m_fMoveSpeed = static_cast<GLfloat>(m_fWindowSize * 2 / static_cast<float>(m_WindowHeight));
}
else
{
    auto viewportAspectRatio = (float)m_WindowHeight / (float)m_WindowWidth;

    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fLeft = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fRight = m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fBottom = (-1.0f)*m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fTop = m_fWindowSize * viewportAspectRatio;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fNear = -(10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
    m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fFar = (10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;

    m_fMoveSpeed = static_cast<GLfloat>(m_fWindowSize * 2 / static_cast<float>(m_WindowWidth));
}
```

And this works fine **UNTIL** I will add any (x,y) offset to my viewport. The effect is following when using `glViewport(0, m_WindowHeight/2,  m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2`):

[image: glViewport(0, m_WindowHeight/2, m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)]

And with `glViewport(0, 0,  m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)`:
[image: glViewport(0, 0, m_WindowWidth/2, m_WindowHeight/2)]

**How can I make it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this problem and posted it on the gamedev forum:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/glviewport-offset-and-ortho-projection/122289#122289

In short: 
I was drawing my whole scene to the framebuffer and then I rendered generated texture to the screen. This operation caused unwanted glViewport()  transformations accumulation.

Solution to this is setting the glViewport() to origin befrore rendering to the framebuffer and then setting offset when rendering texture to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, aspect ratio is always width/height.

Then I think what you are looking for is :

```
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fLeft = x;
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fRight = x + m_WindowWidth;
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fBottom = y;
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fTop = y + m_WindowHeight;
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fNear = -(10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
m_ProjectionMatrix.m_fFar = (10.0f)*m_fWindowSize;
```

Have a look at this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)

Comment: Well, that doesn't work. Could you edit your post and decribe how have you come up with this solution? And maby share refference to it? Because wiki page about ortho projection have no information about it.